# Why return an unknown value when I added a char to null string (as "" + c)?

Tags: c++, string, char

Allow me to show you my code first:

```
void testStringAdd(){
   char c = '$';
   string str = "";
   str += c;//the same as `str = str + c;`
   cout << str << "---";
   cout << "size : " << str.size() << endl;
   str = "" + c;//the same as `str = c + ""`;
   cout << str << "---";
   cout << "size : "<< str.size() << endl;
}
```

I expected the output is:

> $---size : 1
>
> $---size : 1

But the real output on vs2013 is:

> $---size : 1
>
> ---size : 0

This is an interesting phenomenon, and I wonder why it is so weird?

note: If I code `string str = "";` then `str == ""` will return true.

Comment: There's actually a warning issued about this: [_`main.cpp:12:8: warning: offset outside bounds of constant string`_](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5180c0f835abc759).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `str = "" + c;`, `""` is not `std::string`, it's a [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) with type `const char[]`, and then decay to `const char*` and `"" + c` becomes pointer arithmetic.

In this case, since `c` has a positive value, `"" + c` will lead to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means anything is possible. It might be lucky (or unlucky) for you the program doesn't crash.

And as the comments pointed, an explicit conversion to `std::string` will fix the issue.

```
str = std::string("") + c;
```

Or use [std::string literal operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) (since C++14):

```
str = ""s + c;
```

Comment: ... And you are lucky the thing did not fall over

Comment: wont `str = std::string("") + c;` fix the issue ?

Comment: And in C++14, you could use [the standard user-defined literals feature (in this case, compiler provided literals)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Standard_user-defined_literals) to simplify a bit, to: `str = ""s + c;` where the trailing `s` makes `""s` a `std::string` literal, not a `const char[]`. Cleaner looking than explicit constructor wrapping (and I believe trivially faster since it uses the compile time known length instead of searching for `NUL` bytes at runtime).